# Sqlite check condition on creating table

Tags: android, regex, sqlite

Have problem with sqlite check condition then executing sql

Raw query

```
CREATE TABLE commands (
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
command CHAR(16) NOT NULL CHECK(command ~ '^[0-9a-fA-F]')
);
```

error is on **~** symbol
"*Failure near **~** symbol when preparing create...*"

I want that command must match hex value, maybe there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite expressions don't have an `~` operator. It's possible to use regular expressions with the `REGEXP` operator [if your program defines a regexp() function for SQLite to call](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#regexp) (with any luck, your DBI library takes care of this for you).